# Inconsistent offensive/spam flag format on flagging summary page

Tags: feature-request, flags, flag-history

First time I had to use the offensive flag. The answers were obviously offending/spam but it took quite a while to delete them. I was interested in how long it actually took, because an off-topic question posted later got closed much faster.

Instead of finding this information, I noticed the *offensive* (and also *spam*) flag's description is formatted very different. It also contains less information.

[image: offensive flag]

- *"flagged as"* seems redundant - I know that I flagged it, and I'm on the flag summary page after all. The normal flagging doesn't tell me that.
- <del>It is *Helpful*, but a normal flags are *helpful*.</del> (fixed)
- There is no information about the time I flagged it.
- The normal flag's *"helpful"* text contains a tooltip showing the time of it's acceptance, the offensive/spam flags don't.

I like that it's red, but I think the format should be more like that of the other flags. It should show the time somewhere.

Comment: Although this one is older, the other is more focused on the real request being asked here thus my decision.

Comment: I'm good with this as a duplicate. I tried too include the use case for why it should be changed but I guess inconsistency alone suffices as a reason.